# Add remove button to an HTML table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code in which I'm populating an HTML table using a JSON object obtained from an AJAX function

what I want is adding a remove button beside each row, so when the user clicks remove the row will be deleted. I manage to handle the removing process and table binding, but I just want to know how to add the button beside each row.

This is my code where the HTML table is populated:

```
 $.each(ddd, function (key, value) {
                    var tr = $("<tr />");
                    $.each(value, function (k, v) {
                        tr.append($("<td />", {html: v})[0].outerHTML);
                        $("#dataTable").append(tr);
                    })
                })
```

Any suggestions please!

Comment: Why the `[0].outerHTML`? You are unnecessarily regenerating the element.

Comment: the table and its elements are being generated without any issue! @Vohuman

Comment: I didn't mean it doesn't work, I said "You are unnecessarily regenerating the element". `tr.append($("<td />", {html: v}))` is enough. This is, however; unrelated to the question.

Comment: anyways, thanks @Vohuman for your notice,